# Creating of N block table with its automatic size detecting

Tags: imagemagick, montage

Using montage of image-magic I am trying to stack two types of the images producing vertincal table with 2 lines and x columns

```
montage \( "${output}/proc*.png" \) \( "${output}/${target}*.png" \) -geometry 1200x900+1+1 -frame 4 -background white -mattecolor lightgoldenrod2 -mode Frame -bordercolor white ${output}/${project_summary}.png
```

the problem that instead of 2 lines it produces the rectangular table mixing the both types of the images. This could be fixed using -tile x2. How could I determine tile size (x2 in this case) automatically according to the number of the blocks in the montage defined as ( "${output}/image_type.png" )

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Please add a diagram or two making clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: In my example I have two blocks joine together vertically \( "${output}/proc*.png" \) \( "${output}/${target}*.png" \) . So I have to provide an option -tile x2 to define the two rows. Would it be possible to define the number of rows (-tilexN) automatically depending on the number of the provided blocks  \( \)  ?

Comment: Yes, if you provide 3 blocks you can use `-tile x3`. I don't think I'm getting it... that's why I asked for a diagram.

Comment: How can you not know how many blocks you have?

Comment: Furthermore, submitting groups of files in batches enclosed within parentheses is pointless - it makes no difference if you submit 2 groups of 3 images in parentheses or 6 images one after the other with no parentheses. What are you actually trying to do?